# Protractor Test Scripts are executing faster than the page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am automating an angular js website which has a login functionality. All I want to Click on sign in link and enter username and password. But Somehow my script are executing really fast than the page load. Please advice me on how I can handle this: 
My Login Page object is:

```
'use strict'
// Normal Login 
require('../page-objects/loginPage.js');
var customerPortalHome = function () {

    this.clickSignIn = function () {
        browser.sleep(5000);
        element(by.linkText('Sign In')).click();
        browser.waitForAngular();
        browser.sleep(2000);
        return require('./loginPage.js');

    }

}


module.exports = new customerPortalHome();
```

My Test Spec is;

```
var co = require('co');
var UI = require('./ui.js');
var ui = new UI();
var CustomerPage = require('../page-objects/customerPortalHome.js')

describe(" Smoke Test Login to the application", function () {

        it("test", co.wrap(function* () {
            var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
             browser.get(ui.createStartLink());
            expect(browser.getTitle()).toContain("Portal");
            // Verify if user is able to Login into the application
            var loginPage =  CustomerPage.clickSignIn();
            loginPage.switchToFrame('account-sdk');
            var reportPage = loginPage.clickLogin('$$$$$@gmail.com', '$$$$$');
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('reports');
            reportPage.clickSignOut();
            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("?signout");
            browser.sleep(800);
        }));

    });
```

Whenever I execute the test The browser opens for a sec and then closes.

My Onprepare method looks like this:

```
beforeLaunch: function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
        });
    },
    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);

        afterEach(co.wrap(function* () {
            var remote = require('protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote');
            browser.driver.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());



        }));
```

Comment: yes Protractor are lightening fast with Angular. We can use sleep if we need to slow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using browser sleep is never a good idea the best thing to do is to wait for an element and use the then function to do so.

```
element(by.xpath("xpath")).click().then(function(){
      var list = element(by.id('id'));
      var until = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
      browser.wait(until.presenceOf(list), 80000, 'Message: took too long');
    });
```

Comment: HI Acid.... Yes...but I am wondering why is my implicit wait not working...

Comment: looks like ur changing frame.. can us implement the above solution after the change of frame?

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf($$('.desk-sidebar > li').get(num-1)), 60000);
```

Usually，I use this wait.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an ignoreSynchronisation without putting the false somewhere in your page objects helpers?

Be careful, the login can sometimes break the waitForAngular when there are a lot of redirections. I ended up using a dirty sleep to wait the page to be loaded when logging (no other solution were found, ignoreSync, EC for a change of url and wait for an element were not working solutions).

You should also share the error you get.